# How to allow textbox only to accept Japan characters, number and word in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I try to search about RegEx and find some answer. But it isn't full.
Example:

Only accept Japan character:

```
(?:\xEF\xBD[\xA1-\xBF]|\xEF\xBE[\x80-\x9F])|[\x20-\x7E]
```

Only accept number and word:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

But I don't incorporate together. Please help!

**Update answer**

```
/^[\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}a-zA-Z0-9]+$/iu
```

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` won't accept a letter or digit.

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry, i don't know so much about regex

Comment: What do you want to match? What type of Japanese characters?

Comment: @hwnd all of type Japanese characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the following [**Unicode properties**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) and alphanumeric set in a character class.

```
/^[\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}a-z0-9]+$/iu
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to accept special character !@#$%^&*()